# 64bit centos m2crypto crash during load_key

Tags: python, 64-bit, centos, m2crypto

I'm trying to run m2crypto on 64 bit centos 5.6 and/or rhel 5.6. I've compiled python 2.6 and placed into a separate directory (necessary on centos/rhel). I've tried compiling m2crypto against the built-in openssl 0.9.8e as well as manually compiled 0.9.8e, and the behavior is the same. I've even tried epel's python26 and python26-m2crypto. It also crashes.

```
[root@ip-10-172-10-135 ~]# /usr/local/bin/python m2test.py 
Segmentation fault
```

The code is:

```
from M2Crypto import EVP

file = './foo'
cert_priv_key = EVP.load_key(file)
```

The key foo (generated with openssl genrsa for this test):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBAK/y+9J2tnTq0ZhesUV2BjtbY2ND+ZBsIPMACUCFGTbMS59JJ05e
0s2WVqb7ljvm/KsWtJ9qoqnljeaX64E9llECAwEAAQJABZOA0Zm7jJcIj3ioy5fC
+MybqMC1vxL+NFVS9b2CIA9p/f/F/FAZtSOL/+FvvccxnhNogB+J4VMXTbbEURn0
5QIhANceLguDtazhDyjj+tVyIvGrkOfPEUs3lNWpiVABYea7AiEA0WMvE+SImzug
Tj+PSDf2puHQqvoBFz9qJ+5pcT1EVGMCIHOMx4jx162kOqNpSnxK0dBkqvKJfK2d
jnnylkp+Y5svAiBbH4f4Z0eQDvXnt796VWiRHcr67YwV+vIO6LGYp2oaMwIhAKBc
ig+JAHsT9R5Gq9TZ67YcdfI4LHFdswXw/e7eBCs4
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This same test works on 32bit (and of course our application uses this a lot). Perhaps I've compiled python or openssl with the wrong options for 64 bit. Both have shared libs enabled and installed, added to ldconfig, etc.

Anyone have any hints? Has anyone successfully run python26+m2crypto on 64bit?

Comment: you should add your update as a proper answer; editing the answer into your question is incorrect.

Comment: @JvilHuber: Post the solution as an answer and accept it, please. This is how it works on StackOverflow.

Comment: Isn't this more of a SuperUser item, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with the version of swig I was using to compile m2crypto. I was using something on the order of swig-1.3.29-2.el5. Upgrading to the latest swig and recompiling m2crypto fixes the issue. See for reference https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707676

Answer (score 0):

For Centos5 I did the following:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir rpmbuild
cd rpmbuild/
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/swig/swig/swig-1.3.40/swig-1.3.40.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fswig%2Ffiles%2Fswig%2Fswig-1.3.40%2F&ts=1356897393&use_mirror=ignum
tar xzvf swig-1.3.40.tar.gz
cd swig-1.3.40
./configure
make
make install
yum info swig
/usr/local/bin/swig -version
mv /usr/bin/swig /usr/bin/swig-1.3.29
cd /usr/bin/
ln -s /usr/local/bin/swig
```

Then in the next step entered my virtualenv dir, activated it, removed all M2crypto-eggs from the site-packages. Then downloaded the m2crypto sources via yum, untar-ed it, entered the dir, and executed the `./fedora_setup.py`. That's it. Done.

No dependency problems occured with the latest Centos5 updates.